# Theatron Agrippa unable to connect 5.1

Tags: audio, speakers, sound-card, 5.1

[image: Connections Image]

I’m trying to configure a *Theatron Agrippa* with a 5.1 configuration. The thing is that I don’t have a 5.1 speaker system available at the time, but  my Enterprise needs to test 5.1 works although, so I’m trying to configure the 5.1 system connecting 3 headsets  to Line In, Front and Subwoofer channel.  I have the theory that my device can’t configure a 5.1 configuration because there are no speakers connected to the *Theatron Agrippa*, and the PC detects that there is a headset connected, and sends all the 5.1 sound to the headset connected in the front channel, leaving the other two headsets without sound.

What do you think about that?
Do you think that a real 5.1 speaker system will work?